# Sum of normed function spaces equipped with two-parameter family of norms, Dual inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Let $(\cdot,\cdot)$ be the $L^2(\Omega)$ scalar product, and let $V=L^1(\Omega)$, $W=H^{-1}(\Omega)$ (the dual space of $H_0^1(\Omega)$). My question is if there exists a constant $C$, such that for all $a,b>0$ it holds

$$
\inf_{f=v+w} \{a^{-1}\|v\|_{V}+b^{-1}\|w\|_{W} \}\leq C \sup_{a\|g\|_{V^*}+b\|g\|_{W^*}=1}(f,g)\quad\forall f \in C_c^\infty(\Omega).
$$

EDIT: Note that I switched the roles of spaces and duals. Also, the reason I am asking is that I read that

$$(\phi_n,\psi)\leq \|\psi\|_{L^\infty}+o(n)\|\psi\|_{H^1_0}\quad\forall \psi\in C^\infty_c(\Omega)
$$
implies that $\phi_n=\phi^{(1)}_n+\phi^{(2)}_n$ with $\phi^{(1)}$ bounded in $L^1$ and $\phi_n^{(2)}$ compact in $H^{-1}$. Maybe this is true for another reason?

Comment: Do you rather mean $V = C(\bar\Omega)$ or $V = C_0(\Omega)$ instead of $V = C(\Omega)$? And $f \in C_0^\infty(\Omega)$ in the last line?

Comment: What exactly is $(f,g)$ here?

Comment: @grew I fixed it. Pondered about it after reading a paper, but remembered it incorrectly.

Comment: @Normal Human: $(f,g)=\int_{\Omega} fg dx$